# I can't launch a session using Protractor

Tags: selenium, protractor, selenium-chromedriver

I am on Windows 10

1. I installed Node.js
2. use `npm install -g protractor`
3. did `webdriver-manager update`
4. chromedriver is 2.21 and up to date according to update

Issue: When I try to launch a session using (the example on protractortest.org tutorial)

```
protractor conf.js
```

I get the following exception and a blank chrome browser with "data:," in the address bar

> 12:57:10.037 WARN - Exception thrown
>   java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
>   org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException:
>   java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException Build info: version:
>   '2.52.0', revision: '4c2593c', time: '2016-02-11 19:06:42' System
>   info: host: 'ADOAN-790', ip: '172.18.7.104', os.name: 'Windows 10',
>   os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_73' Driver
>   info: driver.version: unknown

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Chrome 53+ you need to have at least `chromedriver` 2.25 installed ([source](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads)). And, since protractor sort of "ships"/"depends on" a particular version of chromedriver through `webdriver-manager` package, you need to **update Protractor to at least 4.0.10** which [has chromedriver 2.25 configured](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#dependencies). If using global `protractor`:

```
npm cache clean
npm install -g protractor
webdriver-manager update
```

If using local:

```
npm cache clean
npm install protractor
webdriver-manager update
```

FYI, related issue:

- [Running protractor on Chrome 54 fails](https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/3639)

Comment: AWESOME! outdated protractor was the issue, updating it did the trick, thank you much

Answer (score 0):

You need to manually update chrome driver, that's not the latest version. Try updating to the latest Chromedriver package:

```
npm install chromedriver@^2.25
```

Don't forget to `-g` or `--save-dev` depending on your requirements.

#### Edit

Try copying the **chromedriver.exe** from */node_modules/chromedriver/lib/chromedriver* to */node_modules/selenium/* (<-- not sure about this path, but I think you just need to find the 2.21 exe and replace it with the latest one)

Comment: Hi, i've update chrome driver to 2.25 using the command you provided, but i still run into the same exception and i see that it is still using Chrome driver 2.21, how do i get protractor to use 2.25?